# how can i test login password

Tags: authentication, phpseclib

i have a project to use phpseclib  connect  cisco and H3C  Swtich device .

these devices' passowrd are not different.so i must try to test these password ,when i first login these device.

i write some code  to find the correct password in the password list,but the correct password is only effect when it's first used to login .

```
  function loginssh_keybo(){
    $user = user::find()->all();
    $ssh = new SSH2($this->ip);
    if (@$ssh->login($user[$this->i]->username, $user[$this->i]->password)) {
      return $ssh;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}

function loginssh_pass(){
    $user = user::find()->all();
    $ssh = new SSH2($this->ip);
    if (@$ssh->login($user[$this->i]->username, $user[$this->i]->password, $user[$this->i]->password)) {
        return $ssh;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
function loginssh()
{
    $user = user::find()->all();
    $max = 3;
    $this->i = 0;
    do {
        if (@$ssh=$this->loginssh_keybo()) {
            $this->islogin = True;
            break;
        } elseif (@$ssh=$this->loginssh_pass()) {
            $this->islogin = True;
            break;
        }  elseif
        ($this->i > $max) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->i += 1;
    } while (!$this->islogin);
    $this->user = $user[$this->i]->username;
    $this->password = $user[$this->i]->password;
    return $ssh;
}
```

Comment: Looks like this has been cross posted this at https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1144 .

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/1144:

```
if ($ssh->login('username', 'password1')) {
    return true;
}
if ($ssh->login('username', 'password2')) {
     return true;
}
if ($ssh->login('username', 'password3')) {
     return true;
}
return false;
```